# Why am I seeing a bomb icon on my files and folders in Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, rabbitvcs

Why am I seeing a bomb icon on all folders and files on my desktop?

I am new to Ubuntu. I tried to Google about it but only found articles about Fork Bomb attacks etc.  After reading a lot on the internet, I am still not sure why I am getting the icon, pictured below.

[image]

Update: Yes RabbitVCS is installed on the machine.  I determined it by executing the below command:

```
dpkg -l | grep "rabbit"
```

I have packages `rabbit`, `rabbit-mode`, `rabbitvcs-cli`, `rabbitvcs-core`, `rabbitvcs-gedit` and `rabbitvcs-nautilus` installed.

Comment: Do you have [RabbitVCS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitvcs/X3HqMw2G7YA) or [Apache (unlikely)](http://serverfault.com/questions/557852/what-would-cause-apache-to-display-a-bomb-icon-for-a-specific-directory) installed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the icon you are seeing is [this one](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/blob/master/data/icons/hicolor/scalable/emblems/emblem-rabbitvcs-error.svg):
[image: bomb icon]

It is a emblem included with [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/), which apparently [indicates a error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitvcs/X3HqMw2G7YA):

> The bomb emblem means that there is some sort of error in the status
>   checker.  It is possible that error messages will show up in
>   `~/.config/rabbitvcs/RabbitVCS.log` but I'm not sure it will for your
>   problem.  I'm not sure what would cause your status checker to be
>   getting errors but it could be that your svn or git dependencies are
>   not correctly installed, or installed in a way that doesn't work with
>   RabbitVCS.  Are the bomb emblems showing up in git repositories or svn
>   repositories or both?
>
> One thing that might help is restarting the status checker.  You can
>   do this by killing the checkerservice.py process.  Run "`ps aux | grep rabbitvcs`" and kill the process that says checkerservice.py.  Once you
>   do that, restart nautilus and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a "conflict" betwen versions. I resolved it,then i saw that the bomb icon stayed there,despite there was no more conflicts, so i used "nautilus -q" to close all nautilus processes, (i'm using nautilus as files administrator).
  This should work, rabbitVCS is installed as a plugin on your files administrator, you have to reload it completly to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! For me there were no conflicts. I only had to close all nautilus windows, run "nautilus -q" and then open one again.